# How to check that which PFUsers are currently using my iOS application or logged-In status?

Tags: ios, objective-c, chat, pfuser

I am developing a iOS base Chat Application, where i want to 
**Display the current online/offline status** 
of my application user. For database i am using parse.com where all chat records and User details are stored.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide us with material of code that you have already tried or currently implemented. Your question is too broad right now and creates opinion based answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a boolean column (PFUser Class) where it changes to TRUE when the user opens the app, and changes to FALSE when the app is closed (or in background)

Comment: Is it there any other option like in-built methods or something else?

Comment: Not that I know of. :)

Comment: Ok means when user will login he the boolean field will be "true" and on logout "false". But in case if internet is not available after login, than also user will display "Online" which is incorrect. So how will manage this thing.?

Comment: Thats why implementing a chat application on Parse is not the best solution. Try looking into node.js and use parse as your database (using REST API). Sorry. :)